# matching variables to condition

Tags: bash

i want to write a new script but i'm absolutely n00b in bash scripting
for example i want that script do kubectl get cs ( check cluster health ) and stdout of kubectl get cs is here:

```
administrator@rgv:~$ kubectl get cs 
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE              ERROR
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health": "true"}   
scheduler            Healthy   ok                   
controller-manager   Healthy   ok
```

How I'm to parse the STATUS column?

If three nodes are the in cluster and the cluster is healthy I want to print just `"cluster healthy."`. If one node is down print `"cluster is to die."`

Comment: I am not sure why there is a downvote on this one.. The op has already shown some effort from his side.. Just that is stuck at this point.. Downvoting without comments doesn't help at all.. :-(

Comment: Like any modern command, `kubectl` seems to have an option to produce machine-readable output so you don't have to parse it. For example, `-o=json` to get output in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool called `awk`.

```
kubectl get cs | awk 'NR>1 && $2=="Healthy"{count++}
                END{if(count==3){print "All healthy"}
                else{
                print "Cluster(s) dead"
                }
                }'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the STATUS field has a `Healthy` status.

If you want to parse it as to find out which line contains the string you can use `grep`:

For your example it would be: `kubectl get cs | tr -s ' ' | cut -f2 -d ' ' | grep Healthy` which would show you all the lines containing a `healthy` string in the second column which is `STATUS`.

To check if cluster is down you can use: `kubectl get cs | tr -s ' ' | cut -f2 -d ' ' | grep Down`.

Note: `tr -s ' '` squeezes the spaces and then you pipe-it to cut it with `cut -f2 -d ' '` which will give you whole the column.  There is space between the two single quotes ('') thank you for noticing @ilkkachu.

If you want to use it in a script you can do create a file using:

`vim cluster_check.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

if kubectl get cs | tr -s ' ' | cut -f2 -d ' ' | grep -q  'Healthy'; 
then
    echo 'cluster healthy!'
else
    echo 'cluster is to die!'
fi
```

Then exit vim with `ESC` `:wq`
Change the execution flag for `chmod +x cluster_check.sh`.

Then you can execute it via: `./cluster_check.sh`

Comment: @ilkkachu good point.  He could add `-d ""` to define space as separator.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: I think you mean `-d " "` (with the space). But that doesn't work either, since `cut` finds empty fields between the spaces separating the columns... Something like `cut -c22-28` would work but it's a bit iffy. `cut` doesn't really work too well for output like this :(

Comment: @ilkkachu: ehm, yes -d " ". Finally found script.  You have to add `tr` there. Sigh, will edit it again.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic approach:

```
if kubectl get cs | tail -n +2 | grep -vq Healthy ; then
    echo "It's dead, Jim"
else
    echo "All is fine in the realm!"
fi
```

`tail -n +2` skips the first line, and the `grep` looks for lines that *don't* contain the string `Healthy`. That is, even one line without it will trigger the warning.

This, of course ignores the columns completely, so it will fail if a dead member can contain that same string elsewhere in the line.